# ios - Firestore still overwrites my data?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add data into my firestore however, I've followed the documentation with the SetOptions.merge() method but it is still overwriting my data

Here's my code

```
 docRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("\(userID!)").document("\(self.dateChose)")
        let dataToBeSaved: [String: Any] = ["workout name": routineNames, "workout sets": routineSets, "workout Reps": routineReps]
        docRef.setData(dataToBeSaved, options: SetOptions.merge()) {(error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

        }
```

I am not sure what I did wrong here or what I should do instead so that I can append a newly added workout (with names, reps, and sets) by my app user into my cloud firestore

thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Merging only works at the field level, it does not support appending to arrays or maps.

This means it only affects the field(s) you are writing, but for those fields it overwrites.

You have 2 options:

1. Do a read-write transaction to append it to the field in question (which requires you to be online)
2. Write each workout as a separate document in a `workouts` subcollection under the user document

Comment: tried doing option 2 but it still overwrites what I had